# How to store string of ASCII into array in ascending order

Tags: arrays, assembly, ascii

I am trying to take in a string of comma separated ASCII numbers convert them to halfwords. Then place them in an array with ascending order. I know how to get the halfwords but the problem is the ascending order. Since the way I have it going so that it reads a char then if its not null or a comma it will store the digit in a variable and then once it reaches a comma it combines the two ASCII digits into one halfword (unless there is only one digit).I am guessing I would store it in the array after that but I am not sure how to know where to put it. This is in Assembly.

EDIT:
This is all the conversion code I have. At the end it goes to loop_end1 if no duplicate has been found and then adds that to the array (this is where I need to add the ascending order stuff). It goes to loop_end2 if a duplicate has been found, thus not putting it in the array. You get to done once null is reached, meaning the end of the string. In done all it does it subtract the amount of elements in the array from the number of elements in the string to find the number of elements eliminated. Thanks for your help

```
L1:
mov a1, addrs  #move the first char of string into 'a1'                                                                                                
sb fc, a1      #store the char in fc
cmp fc,0       #is the char null?
je done        #if the char is null, youre done
jne L2         #if the char is not null goto L2

L2:         
cmp fc,2C  #is the char a comma?
jne L3 
inc addrs
sub dige,dige,dige  #make dige 0, the complicated way
jal L5     #comma has been found put the previous numbers in array

L3:
    sub fc, fc,48  #turn to decimal from ASCII
    cmp dige,1     #is this the second or first 
    jne L4
    lb sd          #holds second digit
    sb sd,fc
    add dige,dige,1 
    jal L1

L4:    
    lb fd     #holds first digit
    sb fd,fc
    inc addrs
    add dige,dige,1
L5: 
    cmp dige,2
    jne L6
    mov $t0,fd
    sll fd,3       #this multipies the first digit by 2^3 (8). now add 2 more
    add fd,fd,$t0
    add fd,fd,$t0  #in total multiplies by 10 because fd*8+fd+fd=fd*10 
    add $t1,fd,sd
    lh hw          #holds halfword of number
    sb hw,$t1   
    mov ecx,0
    jal loop_start

L6:
     lh hw
     sb hw,fd
     mov ecx,0  #inc counter to compare to array length

loop_start: 
    cmp ecx, ARRAY_LENGTH #does ecx equal the number of elem?
    jge loop_end1
    cmp hw,Array1[ecx*8]
    add ecx,1 
    je loop_end2
    jal loop_start 

loop_end1:  
    mov [addra1],hw
    add count,1
    inc addra1
    jal L1

loop_end2:  
    add count,1
    jal L1

done:
sub count,count,ARRAY_LENGTH  #subtracts array length from count to find number of elements eliminated
```

Comment: Can you show some code that you've attempted?

Comment: Which CPU is this for? The code looks like a hodge-podge of x86 and MIPS assembly.

Comment: it is meant to be MIPS.. what code is x86?

Comment: This for example: `cmp ecx, ARRAY_LENGTH`